# how to get the recaptcha value so that it can be used in a condition check

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

Before I added a recaptcha in my website, I have a form that used for user post all user inputs into my db. however I disabled the submit button if there's a field that's still empty, or valued 0. I used jQuery to done this

[image]

I've tried something like using val() method to catch the recaptcha valeu but seems not working.

This is my jQuery to enable submit or disable it after checking all the fields :

```
$('#identity-next').attr('disabled', true); //disable the button
function checkFilled() {
    $('form').on('keyup change', function () {
        if ($(name).val() != "" 
         && $(birth_place).val() != 0 
         && $(birth_date).val() != "" 
         && $(email).val() != "" 
         && $(phone_number).val() != "" 
         && $(address_province).val() != 0 
         && $(address_regency).val() != 0 
         && $(address_district).val() != 0 
         && $(specify_address).val() != 0 
         && $(captcha).val() != "") // the one that's not working { 
            $('#identity-next').attr('disabled', false); return true;
        } 
        else { 
            $('#identity-next').attr('disabled', true); 
            return false; 
        }
    }); 
}

checkFilled() //call the function
```

this is my captcha div :

```
<div id="captcha" name="g-recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" 
     data-sitekey="########################">
</div>   

{!! NoCaptcha::renderJs() !!}

<span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('g-recaptcha-response') }} 
</span>
```

so I want my jquery function could handle the same functionality to enable the submit button when all fields not empty including my recaptcha, I'm using recaptcha V2 btw. in this condition, my button will keep disabled coz the captcha return no value at all(?).

Best regards!.

Comment: What reCAPTCHA version are you using?

Comment: I saw it was V2 version. May I know what is the value of the variable `captcha` in && `$(captcha).val() != "")` ?

Comment: One reason why it is not working is because you have put a comment on that line which in turn makes the opening brace of the `if` statement into a comment also. `&& $(captcha).val() != "") // the one that's not working { `

Comment: I added the comment in my question in this site, not in my actual code

Comment: ok please look at my answer below

Comment: I edited the answer by putting hash `#` to connote this as an `id` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is this:

```
if($("#g-recaptcha-response").val()!="") {
    //show button
}
```

[image]

Comment: would u explain where's this #g-recaptcha-response come from?

Comment: Does that code work from your end? By the way, it is the response from Google's servers. Clicking the I'm not a robot checkbox and/or completing subsequent checks issues a request to Google in which a response will be received at your side.

Comment: yes sure, but if you see that code, you trying to get the value from and ID called g-recaptcha-response, but in my html DOM, there's no ID called that. so im confused here, how you want to get the value if the id itslef doesnt exist. btw, i havent tried your solution yet, maybe after done with my job

Comment: g-recaptcha-response is not visible to you as it is generated as part of the reCaptcha plugin initialization. I think just test it on your end to check.

Comment: alright, I will test it out, and surely will tell you the result! thank you m8!

Comment: well it is not working, btw this is my website that i asked in this section https://akpa.net.id so you could see some console errors maybe

Comment: I cannot see your form. Where is is located in the site?

Comment: its on register page sir

Comment: so what ive done, i comment those captcha filter condition, so the button will keep enable even user not completed the captcha yet

Comment: It works on my end. Before clicking the reCAPTCHA checkbox, the `$("#g-recaptcha-response").val()` is "". After clicking the reCAPTCHA checkbox the `$("#g-recaptcha-response").val()` has value "03AOLTBLRAEE2d80NbXH7RgYtJwvjcXeypFbCuJ9SkUVYlz9JHifgg10-7jq5TIXawnrsXOTAp_bYNhcGxJGGtxc9QeF55k_7c7ITpOTl3ch1HLEQhyuuYHyb_GZkpbkND_4gRK6GxJ7FXVuAxw1urYa14noyPavM7WTg77KANbdQsm4v7geiLEwweqpJ0FPSsje-yD42228idvD_4bSyp4xBh9nogJ4_kPNdIczFhW_cqZkSBMUTikakoDTOvivSGYYzxTwT0LyrjyzWyqmCRa8GWAsVIC3Wx0kfgYARUcCDcXZnFjTlxXsOBTvBzPcldUPhqxlCBkPsmmXTdzDRedNWYtTMAJqp2-T1g1VcNYgtIuCP6na-Z9gOFQDIRDON23XgLGy_VlbSg"

Comment: you get that value by just inspecting my website?

Comment: Yes. I also uploaded an image screenshot on the question above.

Comment: you helped me a lot sir!

Comment: maybe the main problem is, i'm too stupid to clear all cache before trying any changes!

Comment: Welcome!. Its my pleasure to help you.